# connecting multiple led strips to a single DC power supply

Tags: dc, led-strip

I have 12 led strips that each came with a 3 amp/12vDC power supply.  I want to connect all 12 strips to one DC power supply.  How do I calculate the size power supply I need? Do I increase the wattage or the amperage?

Comment: First you would have to figure out how much current the led strips really use, maybe from a datasheet, maybe by measuring, because the power supply that comes with it is probably over-rated. Then multiply the amps by 12. Or just buy a 36A /12VDC unit. (And Watts = Amps x Volts. So you can not increase the one without the other)

Answer (score 0):

*Do I increase the wattage or the amperage?*   Both!   Watts are a product of volts multiplied by the current.  **P=I X E** where **P** is watts, **I** is current and **E** is voltage.   You will need to connect your LED strips in parallel, so 12 strips at 3 amps each will be 36 amps.  And 36 amps times 12 volts will be 432 watts.